# Accessing different data object while clicking on different buttons

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a modal skeleton in my HTML, the data for the modal is inside javascript.
I am trying to access different data objects while clicking on different buttons, but I want to use the same modal skeleton.
Currently working on mobile.
live demo: https://adamteddychang.github.io/Hello-Portfolio/
HTML:

```html
<div class="modal" id="modal">
        <div class="modal_dialog">
          <header class="modal_header">
           <h1 class="modal_title"></h1>
            <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close = "modal">
              ✕  
            </button>
          </header>
          <section class="modal_content">
            <ul id="lang-contain_modal">
                
                <li class="lang-li_modal" id="lang1"></li>
                <li class="lang-li_modal" id="lang2"></li>
                <li class="lang-li_modal" id="lang3"></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="" alt="Project Image in Modal" height="220" id="proj_img">
            
            <p id="proj_content"></p>
          </section>
          <div id="modal_buttons">
          <button class="see_btns"><a href="" id="see_live" target="blank">See Live </a><img src="Images/share.png" height="24" alt=""></button>
          <button class="see_btns"><a href="" id="see_src" target="blank">See Source</a><img src="Images/whitegithub.png" height="24" alt=""></button>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

code for button 1: `<button id="st-see-btn" type="button" data-open = "modal" >See Project</button>`

code for button 2: `<button class="st-see-btn_2" type="button" data-open = "modal">See Project</button>`

```
The object in question
```

```js
const modal1 = {  
    title :"Multi Post Stories",
    language1: "html",
    language2: "Bootstrap",
    language3: "Ruby on Rails", 
    projectImage: "Images/modal_img.png",
    projectTxt: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essent",
    live:"https://www.google.com",
    source:"https://www.github.com"  
}
```

Edit:

```js
//Data for Modal for first project
 modalTitle.innerHTML = modal1.title
 languages1.innerHTML = modal1.language1
 languages2.innerHTML = modal1.language2
 languages3.innerHTML = modal1.language3
 projectImg.src = modal1.projectImage
 projectContent.innerHTML = modal1.projectTxt
 seeLiveBtn.href = modal1.live
 seeSrcBtn.href = modal1.source

 //Data for Modal for second project
 modalTitle.innerHTML = modal2.title
 languages1.innerHTML = modal2.language1
 languages2.innerHTML = modal2.language2
 languages3.innerHTML = modal2.language3
 projectImg.src = modal2.projectImage
 projectContent.innerHTML = modal2.projectTxt
 seeLiveBtn.href = modal2.live
 seeSrcBtn.href = modal2.source
```

I want to access the first part when I click on the first button and second part when I click on the second button

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and pass the object as a parameter; inside function get element and rewirte value:

```
    const modal1 = {
      title :"Multi Post Stories",
      language1: "html",
      language2: "Bootstrap",
      language3: "Ruby on Rails",
      projectImage: "Images/modal_img.png",
      projectTxt: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essent",
      live:"https://www.google.com",
      source:"https://www.github.com"
    }

    const modal2 = {
      title :"AA",
      ...
    }

    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function(){
      loadDataIntoModal(modal1)
    })

    document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', function(){
      loadDataIntoModal(modal2)
    })

    function loadDataIntoModal(data){
      var modalTitle = document.querySelector('.modal_title');
      modalTitle.innerHTML = data.title
      //TODO: CONTINUE GETTING ELEMENTS WITH querySelector OR getElementById AND REWRITE VALUES
    }
```